# Python: cohorts analysis about calculating ARPU

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column:revenue_sum

```
revenue_sum
10000.0
12324.0
15534.0
26435.0
45623.0
56736.0
56353.0
```

And I want to write a function that creates all new columns at once that shows the sum of revenues.

For example, first row in the 'revenue_1'should show the sum of first two float in revenue_sum;

second row in the 'revenue_1'should show the sum of 2nd and 3rd float in revenue_sum.

First row in the 'revenue_2' should show the sum of first 3 float in revenue_sum

```
revenue_sum   revenue_1    revenue_2
10000.0        22324.0      47858.0
12324.0        27858.0      54293.0
15534.0        41969.0      87592.0
26435.0        72058.0      128794.0
45623.0        102359.0     158712.0
56736.0        113089.0     NaN
56353.0        NaN          NaN
```

Here is my code:

```
'''python

df_revenue_sum1 = df_revenue_sum1.iloc[::-1]

len_sum1 = len(df_revenue_sum1)+1
def func(df_revenue_sum1):
    for i in range(1,len_sum1):
        df_revenue_sum1['revenue_'+'i']=
        df_revenue_sum1['revenue_sum'].rolling(i+1).sum()
return df_revenue_sum1

df_revenue_sum1 = df_revenue_sum1.applymap(func)
'''
```

And it shows the error:

"'float' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index revenue_sum'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be an easier way to do this without a for loop. The pandas function rolling (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) might do what you need. It sums along a sliding window specified by the min_periods and window parameters. Min periods means how many values it should sum at least. Window means it will  sum at most that many values. Applying this works as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# The dataframe provided
d = {
    'revenue_sum': [
        10000.0,
        12324.0,
        15534.0,
        26435.0,
        45623.0,
        56736.0,
        56353.0
    ]
}

# Reverse the dataframe because rolling only looks backwards and
# we want to make a rolling window forward
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = d1[::-1]

# apply rolling summing 2 at a time
df['revenue_1'] = df['revenue_sum'].rolling(min_periods=2, window=2).sum()
# apply rolling window 3 at a time
df['revenue_2'] = df['revenue_sum'].rolling(min_periods=3, window=3).sum()

print(df[::-1])
```

This gave me the following dataframe:

```
   revenue_sum  revenue_1  revenue_2
0      10000.0    22324.0    37858.0
1      12324.0    27858.0    54293.0
2      15534.0    41969.0    87592.0
3      26435.0    72058.0   128794.0
4      45623.0   102359.0   158712.0
5      56736.0   113089.0        NaN
6      56353.0        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. if the length of 'revenue_sum' is large and It costs a lot of time to create columns one by one. Is there a way to write a function to create all columns at once? THanks

Comment: `for i in range(2, n):
    df['revenue' + str(i - 1)] = df['revenue_sum'].rolling(min_periods=i, window=i).sum()`

Where you would define n to be however many columns you need!